# Partial string search XQuery / XPath (As the LIKE statement in SQL)

Tags: xpath, xquery

With SQL you have the LIKE statement to get results if you only know part of the value. But in XQuery I can't seem to vind a way to search my XML file in this same manner.

This is what I tried but doesn't work:

```
for $c in /parent/child  where $c/element="*partial strin*" return $c/element
for $c in /parent/child  where $c/element="%partial strin%" return $c/element
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't actually need a `for` expression here at all, you can just use a predicate.  For an exact substring match there's the `contains` function:

```
/parent/child/element[contains(., "partial strin")]
```

For more complex matching you can use regular expressions with the `matches` function:

```
/parent/child/element[matches(., "^partial\s+strin")]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the Starts-with() and the Contains() functions, these are both capable of partial search. Given your example above this would be

```
//parent/child[contains(@element, 'partial stri')]
```

note I presume @element is an attribute of child, if you only want to search the text of the child element replace @element with a single " . "